# How can I use recursion on two-tuples to sum up the second values?

Tags: python

Say I have a tuple:

```
x = (20,400), (10,100), (10,200)
```

And I have a value

```
y = 30
```

I'm trying to find all the associated second values whose first values in x add up to less than or equal to y.

So my recursive problem would return 600 because it adds 400 and 200 from 20 and 10. Since 200 is greater than the other 100 associated with 10, it would add that one instead.

```
def recur(x, y):
    if len(x) == 0:
        return x
    else:
        #use recursion here but I can't quite figure it out. 

recur((10,60), (20,100), (30,200), 50) 

# Returns :

 300

# Because it adds 20 and 30 since they both add up to 50 and have the
   highest numbers associated with them.
```

Comment: Can you please post some expected output?

Comment: does it have to be recursive?

Comment: Yes, I'm currently learning recursion methods

Comment: Recursion can be used, but not in the way you think. This is an example of a subset sum problem, which does not admit a greedy algorithm as a solution. You need to read up on dynamic programming.

Comment: Yes this problem is unusual and recursion is probably not the best way to solve it but I'm just starting to learn python

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be solved recursively, but it is probably not particularly efficient and certainly not very elegant. Note how the `wrapper` function prepares the argument by sorting it by the second element of each pair, and how it later sums these elements from the `recur`'s result.

```
def recur(x, y): 
    for i, item in enumerate(x):
        if item[0] == y:
            return [item]
        elif item[0] > y:
            return []
        reduced_set = x[:i] + x[i+1:]
        result = recur(reduced_set, y-item[0])
        if result:
            return [item] + result
    return []

def wrapper(x, y):
    result = recur(sorted(x, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True), y)
    return sum(item[1] for item in result)

x = (20,400), (10,100), (10,200)
print(wrapper(x, 30)) 

x = (10,60), (20,100), (30,200)
print(wrapper(x, 50))
```